# WPF Textbox Focus Behavior is not triggering multiple time

Tags: c#

Focus behavior for a text box when the page is loaded or else dialog box is open

public void attack( object);

```
control.Loaded += OnControleLoaded;
```

The first time OnControleLoaded is focusing but for multiple time its not triggering the method OnControleLoaded

```
private void OnControleLoaded( sender, e)--->DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
            Control control = object as Control;if (control != null)--->control.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Loaded` event triggers only when the control initiated, not when it's focused

Consider using another event like `Click` or `Focus`

Im writing from memory. I don't know exactly what are the TextBox events... Just check them

Good luck :)

**Edit:** try to use `FocusState.Pointer` so the focus triggered from the pointer instead of programmer manual command

From [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.focusstate.aspx):

> **Programmatic**  Element obtained focus through a deliberate call to
>   Focus or a related API.
>
> **Pointer** Element obtained focus through a pointer action.

Comment: as you said the trigger even work, when its initiated? i tried with Click instead of Focus . still have the same problem.

Comment: in the about code the load even it attach to text box for focus behavior. the focus behavior is working when i open it at first. then if i open it multiple time the focus behavior is not working.

Comment: Your code is not formatted correctly and it's hard to read it. You set the focus behavior to be programmatic but when do you call Control.Focus(); again? (So the focus will happen)

Comment: I hope I'll have time to help you later, I don't have a pc now... Sorry